# CAF Receiver, shutdown handling

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

i'm trying to add logic to the shutdown event on my receiver app but every time the sender disconnects, debugger just closes and no logic is executed (like sending some HttpRequests).
My piece of code:

```
this.context.addEventListener(
        cast.framework.system.ShutdownEvent,
        e => {
                this._sendStats();
        });
```

Also tried `cast.framework.system.SHUTDOWN` and `cast.framework.system.SENDER_DISCONNECTED`. 
Is there other way to get the expected result (executing logic on apps shutdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the event type: cast.framework.system.EventType.SHUTDOWN:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.system#.EventType

Comment: this still not guarantee that async action (eg: XHR call) will be executed.

Is it possible to guarantee await of all async actions on the shutdown event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Synthax with CAF Receiver:

```
context.addEventListener(cast.framework.system.EventType.SHUTDOWN,
      e => {
        console.log("Shutdown");
    });
```